# How to connect a React frontend on Netlify to a Flask backend on PythonAnywhere

Tags: reactjs, netlify, pythonanywhere

**TLDR: React app interfaces properly with Flask API on PythonAnywhere when hosted locally but not when a static build is hosted on Netlify. Perhaps the proxy information is missing from the build?**

---

**EDIT 1**:
Here are the errors in the browser console:
[image]

---

I've created a **Flask API** that pulls machine learning models from Amazon S3 and returns predictions on data input from POST requests. I've put this API on **PythonAnywhere**.

I've also created a **React** frontend which allows me to input data, submit it, and then receive the prediction. When I host this app locally, it behaves appropriately (i.e. connecting to the Flask app on PythonAnywhere, loading the models properly, and returning the predictions).

I've tried deploying a static build of the React app on **Netlify**. It behaves as expected, *except* for anything that requires interacting with the Flask App. I have a button for testing that simply calls the Flask app in a GET request, and even this is throwing a 404 error.

I checked the error and server logs on PythonAnywhere and see nothing. The only thing I can thik of is that my proxy which lists the domain of the PythonAnywhere app in my `package.json` file is for some reason unincluded in the build, but I don't know why this would be the case.

Has anyone else run into a similar issue or know how I can check to see if the proxy information is included in the static build? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're probably getting CORS errors. Check the javascript console in your browser and you'll probably see messages about that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just added to my API `from flask_cors import CORS` and `CORS(app) `, where `app` is the Flask application, to no avail. I previously checked the browser console logs and couldn't find the issue, but I've added them to the post in an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Glenn for the help.

## Solution:

1. I realized (embarrassingly late) that the requests were not going to the right address, as can be seen in the browser console error above. I was using a proxy during development, so the netlify app was calling itself rather than the pythonanywhere API. **I simply went into my react code and edited the paths to pythonanywhere**. E.g.

```
onClick={ async () => {
        const response = await fetch("/get", {...}}
```

became

```
onClick={ async () => {
        const response = await fetch("https://username.pythonanywhere.com/get", {...}}
```

2. As @Glenn mentioned, there may have been a CORS issue as well, so in my flask application I utilized `flask_cors`. I can't say for sure that this was necessary given that I didn't test removing it after the fetch addresses had changed, but I suspect that it is necessary.

Hopefully this can help someone else